# How many SSL System.setProperty() options don't work on Android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

Its pretty clear that

- System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL");

does not work on Android. One uses it and gets no error. There is no documentation about what works and what doesn't. One only finds out by simply trying it and seeing that nothing happens.
What other standard SSL-related System.setProperty() methods don't work?
Clearly these don't work

1. System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStoreFileName);
2. System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStoreFileName);
3. System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", 
               keyStorePassword);
4. System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",
           trustStorePassword);

for if they did there would not be all the frustrations with certificates and keystores that Android users have shown in this forum.
This property may not work either, but I am not sure.

- System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "BKS");

Does anyone know just what the list of SSL-related property methods that DO work on Android are? Perhaps none?

Comment: If they don't work it is a violation of the JSSE Specification. Complain to the vendor.

Comment: Android may be not as bad as Apple when it comes to doing what they want want but they are big enough too.